# How does C++ check the truth value of an std::ios object?

Tags: c++, casting, boolean, iostream

When I run code like

```
istream s;
if (s)
  // ...
```

I can test for the truth value of istream (or any ios object). From my understanding, this works the way it does because of how ios defines the `operator!` function. (For reference, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operatornot/.) My question is: why does putting `s` inside the if statement, as above, cause the `operator!` function to be evaluated? As a secondary question, if I put just any object inside an if statement, what are the possible ways that C++ will use to evaluate its truthiness?

Comment: It has an `operator bool()`.

Comment: @chris isn't it `operator void*()` in C++98?

Comment: @Flexo, Yeah, it changed in C++11. The new one is explicit as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++03, this check was done through the `operator void*` member function, which returned a non-null pointer if the stream was in a good state and NULL otherwise.  Since null pointers evaluate to false and non-null pointers evaluate to true, this check worked fine.

It did have problems, though, since you could do this:

```
std::cout << std::cout;
```

This would invoke the `operator void*` function and print out either 0 or the address of `cout`, depending on whether the stream was good.  This isn't a good thing, since the above code doesn't appear to do that.  Worse, you could do

```
delete std::cout;
```

Which causes undefined behavior if the stream isn't good.

In C++11, this was changed so the stream has an `explicit operator bool` member function, which allows the stream to be explicitly cast to a bool.  This eliminates the above problem and is the preferred way to support if checks on objects going forward.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The template `basic_ios` has an `explicit operator bool` that gets called in this context. In the olden days it was `operator void*`, but that was controversial because some people worried that someone might someday write `delete my_stream`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::istream` has an `operator bool()` overload which is invoked in the if statement. `operator!` is also a member function which checks if an error occurred in the stream but is not used inside the if statement in this case.

Comment: `basic_ios` has a member `operator!` that returns `fail()`.